# How to make shuffled number never equal original? (Java)

Tags: java, android, random, int

I have an original number (LoadG1). I then produce shuffled versions of this number as seen in the code below. Note: generateG1 is a `Random`.

```
int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(89999) + 10000;
for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {

StringBuilder charLoadG1 = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(loadG1));
StringBuilder randomLoadG1 = new StringBuilder();
while(charLoadG1.length() != 0) {
int index = generateG1.nextInt(charLoadG1.length());
char c = charLoadG1.charAt(index);
randomLoadG1.append(c);
charLoadG1.deleteCharAt(index);
}

}

 if(Integer.valueof(String.valueof(randomLoadG1))==loadG1) {
for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {

StringBuilder charLoadG1 = new   StringBuilder(String.valueOf(loadG1));
StringBuilder randomLoadG1 = new StringBuilder();
while(charLoadG1.length() != 0) {
int index = generateG1.nextInt(charLoadG1.length());
char c = charLoadG1.charAt(index);
randomLoadG1.append(c);
charLoadG1.deleteCharAt(index);
}
```

}

This successfully rearranges the numbers in loadG1, seen as the value for randomLoadG1. The issue is, I don't want randomLoadG1 to ever be == to loadG1. This can happen if it is rearranged into the exact same order. I tried using a while loop to sort this out, but it only crashed my app whenever an identical randomLoadG1 was produced.

Can anyone help out with explaining how to get randomLoadG1 (the shuffled version(s) of the original loadG1) to never have the same value as loadG1? Any submitted code is greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?  Just check if the generated number is equal to the original number, and if yes, do the generation of the number again.

Comment: Hint: generate it, test it, if OK stop, otherwise repeat

Comment: @Stephen C Please see the added 'if' code above. I don't think it works perfectly, because if the reshuffled numbers have one equal to LoadG1 again, won't the program just continue after that one reshuffle anyway?

Comment: @David Choweller Please see the added 'if' code above. I don't think it works perfectly, because if the reshuffled numbers have one equal to LoadG1 again, won't the program just continue after that one reshuffle anyway?

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to force some arbitrary conditions on random processes. It is expected to sometimes come up with the same result. As a historic example, the Enigma code was broken because it never encrypted a character onto itself.

Comment: @4u53r - Put it in a loop.  Seriously, this should be obvious ...

Comment: @Henry Surely there's a way around this.

Comment: @Stephen C As mentioned in the post, the while loop would crash the app when it would produce an identical number. If you know a way around this considering it's so obvious, please feel free to share.

Comment: Re, "the while loop would crash the app".  Having a loop in your program does not mean that the program must crash.  If you have code that crashes, and you can't figure out why, then that might be a good subject for another stack exchange question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pseudocode implementation:

```
number1 = random number
do {
    number2 = random_shuffle(number1);
} while (number1 == number2)
```

... where `random_shuffle(number1)` stands for your existing shuffle algorithm.

Now I don't understand why you can't refactor your existing implementation to follow this pattern, but it *should be* simple Java programming.  If your code is crashing, then you should use a debugger to find out why.